# How to enable I2C2 on beaglebone black for yocto project?

Tags: yocto, beagleboneblack

I am trying to build yocto project on beaglebone black. I would like to enable I2C2 port on beagle bone. I am newbie in yocto project.
Any pointer or reference document would be helpful.

here is the original file am335x-boneblack-common.dtsi and I would like to modify that file with following content

```
    i2c2_pins: pinmux_i2c2_pins {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <0x178 0x73 0x17c 0x73>;
};
user_leds_pins: pinmux_user_leds {
    pinctrl-single,pins = < AM33XX_IOPAD(0x848, PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE7) >; /* P9.14, gpio1[18] */

};
```

and

```
leds {
compatible = "gpio-leds";
pinctrl-names = "default";
pinctrl-0 = <&user_leds_pins>;
i2c2-live {
    gpios = <&gpio1 18 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
    default-state = "on";
};
```

};

```
&i2c2: i2c@4819c000 {
pinctrl-names = "default";
pinctrl-0 = <&i2c2_pins>;
status = "okay";
clock-frequency = <100000>;
tmp75@4d {
    compatible = "national,lm75";
    reg = <0x4d>;
};
```

};

Kindly suggest how to create patch for above code.

Thanks in Advance

Regards,
Nikhil

Comment: Do you mean activate I2C the user space(in /dev/i2cXX) so you can access the bus from userspace ?

Comment: I would like to access/enable I2C2 port pin for my project. What are the steps to enable it on beaglebone black for yocto project

Comment: You didn't answer the question, how do you want to use the I2C bus? What is your project cast

Comment: I would like to activate/enable I2C2 in device tree but how to add device tree to yocto project. After adding that I have connect temperature sensor to it. What are the correct steps for adding device tree to yocto project.

Comment: Give me the yocto layer, the I2C bus, the sensor name and its address in the I2C bus and I will help you with a custom Layer that activate all of that for you.

Comment: BelHadjSalem TALEL, Thanks for your quick response, LM75 is sensor name. https://github.com/beagleboard/devicetree-source/blob/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-boneblack.dts device tree source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to understand how to deal with your `dts` file.

You need to decide whether you want to work with the official `dts` file that is provided by your linux kernel and patch it. Or, create your own `dts` file and use it instead.

To understand how to patch the `dts` or how to add custom one, I have 2 stackoverflow answers for that, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820230/how-to-apply-patch-file-of-dtsior-dts-in-yocto/67837070#67837070) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68222619/update-custom-device-tree-on-yocto/68226476#68226476).

After you understand that, now lets talk about adding your I2C node.

First, you need to search if your sensor has an official kernel driver.

If it has a driver, then, it has a `compatible` name that is defined in it.

You take that name with the sensor address in that I2C bus and:

For example, adding the sensor of address 0x01 to I2C 1 bus:

```
&i2c1 {
    // ...
    sensor_name: sensor_name@0x01 {
         compatible = "compatible_name";
         reg = "0x01";
    }
}
```

Now, you need to activate the flag of the driver in the kernel `defconfig`

```
bitbake linux-XXX -c menuconfig
```

Activate the flag, and:

```
bitbake linux-XXX -c diffconfig
```

it will generate `.cfg` file containing only the difference.

Take that and add it to your linux recipe:

```
SRC_URI_append = " file://sensor.cfg"
```

Comment: BelHadjSalem TALEL, thanks I will Try above steps.

Comment: hi can you please guide me in patching device tree for beaglebone. i have tried above steps for patching but unable to patch it.

Comment: You can follow steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820230/how-to-apply-patch-file-of-dtsior-dts-in-yocto/67837070#67837070 , just change linux-yocto to the beaglebone linux

Comment: Can any one guide on above.